# UIButton not responding in presented UIViewController in iOS7. Responds in iOS8

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, ios8

I have a view controller I modally present as a popup. There are two buttons in the two upper corners (dismiss and approve) that are not responding to touches in iOS7. Touches works fine on iOS8. 
I have more buttons in that view that do respond to touches and more over if I move those buttons from corners they responds to touches. 
Please help :)

Here is how I present the modal view:

```
 [self.firstAvailableUIViewController.drawerController presentViewController:sdvc animated:YES completion:^{
}];
```

Comment: Can you share the code and/or screenshot from the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Check the frames/bounds of the buttons and the container view (the main view of the view controller) - in runtime, NSLog them. Sometimes buttons are visible, but are actually outside of the bounds of the container, and thus do not respond to touch events.